# Post Increment in while loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

Here is a very simple C program:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i++ < 10)
         printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Why `0` is not the first number to print?
And if I replace the `i++` with `++i` I'll get this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

For both `i++` and `++i` the first number is `1`.

I expected to see the `0` for post increment in while loop `while()`.

 Thanks.

Comment: i++ is incrementing in execution time, of course it's one.

Comment: Regardless of operator used, you print `i` **after** it was modified, so how can you see `0`!?

Comment: `while(i++ < 10) /*i is incremented here*/ printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: C programmers love to downvote on SO for some reason, it's like C is not the most confusing language ever existed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `i++` (and `++i`) is done as part of the `while` expression evaluation, which happens *before* the printing. So that means it will always print `1` initially.

The only difference between the `i++` and `++i` variants is when the increment happens inside the expression itself, and this affects the final value printed. The equivalent pseudo-code for each is:

```
while(i++ < 10)            while i < 10:
                               i = i + 1
    printf("%d\n", i);         print i
                           i = i + 1
```

and:

```
                           i = i + 1
while(++i < 10)            while i < 10:
    printf("%d\n", i);         print i
                               i = i + 1
```

Let's say `i` gets up to `9`. With `i++ < 10`, it uses `9 < 10` for the `while` expression *then* increments `i` to 10 before printing. So the check uses 9 then prints 10.

With `++i < 10`, it first increments `i` *then* uses `10 < 10` for the `while` expression. So the check uses 10 and *doesn't* print anything, because the loop has exited because of that check.

Answer (score 6):

`i++` is *post-increment* and `++i` is *pre-increment*. Post-increment means that the previous value is returned after incrementing the object. Pre-increment means that the object is incremented and then returned. Either way, the object is incremented when its expression is evaluated and that's why you don't get `0` as the first output.

Answer (score 0):

You increment `i` after checking it and before printing it. Either increment after checking and printing, or use a `do while` loop:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    } while(i++ < 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the while loop `while(i++ < 10)` is evaluated it is checking the value of i, adding one to it, and comparing the *old* value to 10. When you change it to `while(++i < 10)` it increments the value of `i` before comparing the new value to 10.

Either way however, by the time you get to the next statement `i` has already been incremented.

If you wanted to print from 0 to 9 you could try

```
    while(i < 10)
     printf("%d\n", i++);
```

instead. In this case the value of `i` is incremented *after* providing its original value to the `printf` statement.

Answer (score -3):

The whie loops is check the conditions is true executed while block   and test the

conditions is false terminate the while loop.

see about post increment within while loop ++

void main()

{

int rmvivek;

clrscr();

printf("ënter the integer values 1 to 10");

scanf("%d",&rmvivek);

while(10>= rmvivek++)

{

printf("the value is=%d\n", rmvivek);

}

getch();

}